# Magento 2 How to exclude configurable product sku from catalog rule

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.4, magento-2.0

I am trying to exclude some list of sku's from catalog price rule, in this list simple and configurable product sku's are there. Successfully excluding for simple products but not working for configurable sku's.

[image]

Comment: did you tried excluding `configurable product sku` ?

Comment: Yes I tried with  excluding configurable product sku and it's child sku's.

Comment: okay, totally how many products you are giving discounts ?

Comment: you can create one attribute and give same value for that attribute for all simple products and assign catalog price rule for that attribute.

Comment: I have catalog rule with 20% discount to wholesale customer group  and I want to exclude list of 80 to 150 products (included with simple and configurable).

Comment: For those 80 to 150 products for each product  individual special price is there for wholesale customer group  so I used customer group price feature in Product advanced pricing this is working but again catalog rule is getting applied even though I excluded from catalog rule

Comment: okay, but you cant delete `catalog price rule` right? seeems that need for other products ? for normal customers

Comment: are you using magento 2 version ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121804/discussion-between-mahendra-and-nsdlfefinedieicbe).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can try create one **attribute** & give value as **"1"** for Products you want to give discounts & give value as **"0"** for Products you want to give discounts.

[image]